# Volume hotkeys not working on P55-a5312 laptop

Tags: keyboard

I have a Toshiba P55-A5312 laptop, I pulled the drive and installed an SSD and Ubuntu 13.04. Everything works except the volume up/down hotkeys. Might anyone have a good place to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `xev` to see what keycode is received by the X display manager when you press the volume keys. In a terminal type `xev`, then while the little window it opens is active press the volume key and check the output on the terminal. You should see something like this :

> KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
>       root 0xc5, subw 0x0, time 63238943, (174,171), root:(176,173),
>       state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False
>
> KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
>       root 0xc5, subw 0x0, time 63239050, (174,171), root:(176,173),
>       state 0x0, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
>       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
>       XFilterEvent returns: False

The interesting part is the keycode. With this you can look at `xmodmap -pke | less`and see what this keycode is bound to. In my system I have `keycode 123 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume` for the volume up key. You can set whatever keycode you found with xev to this by running `xmodmap -e "keycode xxx = XF86AudioRaiseVolume NoSymbol XF86AudioRaiseVolume"`.